# Por que não está sendo limpa a opção selecionada do <select> usando Choosen?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estava tentando limpar a opção selecionada da caixa de seleção - `<select>` usando JavaScript. Nessa caixa de seleção estou usando o plugin [Choosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/).

Vi uma resposta no [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11365340), e já fiz o seguinte código:

```
$("#btnLimpar").click(function(){
            $("#editPublication")[0].reset();
            var cmb = new Array('#cmbCompany','#cmbType','#cmbTitle','#cmbEmployee','#cmbMonth');

            for (var i = 0; i < cmb.length; i++) {
                $(i).val('').trigger('chosen:updated');
            };
        });
```

Entretanto ainda não consegui limpar a opção selecionada. E se uso:

`console.log($(i).val('').trigger('chosen:updated'));`

É retornado informações semelhantes a essa:

> ```
> r.fn.init {}
>     __proto__: Object(0)
>
>  [1]
>     0: 1
>     length: 1
>     __proto__: Object(0)
> ```

Como posso **limpar a opção selecionada no combobox**?

Comment: **_`for`_**????

Comment: Que foi? Qual problema? @LINQ

Comment: Qual o motivo dessa tag?

Comment: Achei que fosse adequada @LINQ.

Comment: Mas por quê? Não entendi a relação da pergunta com `for`

Comment: arrumei la, eu esqueci de salvar

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bxuxk9p2/4/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você está selecionando o índice do *loop* e não o elemento na pagina, veja se o código abaixo funciona:

```
$("#btnLimpar").click(function(){
    $("#editPublication")[0].reset();
    $("#cmbCompany,#cmbType,#cmbTitle,#cmbEmployee,#cmbMonth").val("").trigger("chosen:updated");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A lógica está correta, entretanto, você esqueceu, de incluir a sua variável `cmb` ao *loop*. Perceba que você não usou ela no *loop em si*, simplesmente a declarou, mas dentro do *loop*, você não a utilizou:

```
$(i).val('').trigger('chosen:updated');
```

Você pode adicioná-la, dentro do *loop*, e juntamente com a variável `i`, acessar os índices do seu *array* a cada iteração, para que seja substituída pelos elementos do *array*, dessa maneira:

```
$(cmb[i]).val('').trigger('chosen:updated');
```

Por fim, você pode fazer da seguinte maneira, que irá funcionar:

```
$("#btnLimpar").click(function(){
            $("#editPublication")[0].reset();
            var cmb = new Array('#cmbCompany','#cmbType','#cmbTitle','#cmbEmployee','#cmbMonth');

            for (var i = 0; i < cmb.length; i++) {
                $(cmb[i]).val('').trigger('chosen:updated');
            };
});
```